# SQL Dump File uploading

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a bigger `sql` text file (powerpro.sql --> 350MB) to be uploaded to `phpmyadmin` database named **powerpro-new**.

So, I used the following command in windows

```
C:\mysqldump -uroot -p powerpro-new > "C"\powerpro.sql"
```

But, received the following error.

> 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What may be the error. Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: This might be an issue with PATH environment variable. Try to run this command and check for the mysql install directory in the output: echo %PATH%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should navigate to your mysql installation directory in cmd. The default installation path (MySQL Server 5.6) is:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump.exe -uroot -p powerpro-new > "C"\powerpro.sql"
```

If you don't know where you installed MySQL server you can search mysqldump file by using following command:

```
C:\>dir /S /P mysqldump.exe
```